# Why PHP rounds the results of math operations

Tags: php

The result of below operation should be `0.63686637617647057`, but I get this result instead : `0.63686637617647`.

Result that I expect:

```
1 - 0.36313362382352943 = 0.63686637617647057;
```

Result of php:

```
1 - 0.36313362382352943 = 0.63686637617647
```

How can I do to make php not round the result?

Comment: Please read up about how computers handle floating point numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Check this out: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de)

Comment: There are limits to the precision of variables. If you want to have arbitrary length precision, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php Also read the links given above, but they do not directly help you with your problem.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I've used bcadd and bcsub functions. Thanks

Comment: @tambre Thanks for your help